Get latest Codeigniter version number from official website using php code
I want to get the latest version number of Codeigniter from official website to check if equals with my current Codeigniter version of my app. I want to do this so I can show a message or email myself a text that warns me that framework needs upgrade.
Any ideas how can I do this.

https://api.github.com/repos/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/tags?per_page=1

Hello, I believe your question would be more well-received if you included what you have tried so far, maybe giving a few more details. I hope you get the answer you're looking for!

Yew you' right. Sorry. Although I hadn't try anything because I had no clue how to start. After Olivier's answer, I figured out how I can isolate the number of the latest Codeigniter version.

The code I used to isolate the latest CodeIgniter version from the giving url is bellow:
    $url = "https://api.github.com/repos/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/tags?per_page=1";

try {
  $can_read_url = 1;
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json",
    "User-Agent: Your-Application-Name/version" )
  );

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  $tags = json_decode($response, true);

  $latestTag = $tags[0];
  $latestVersion = $latestTag["name"];

  $latestVersion = ltrim($latestVersion, 'v');

  if ($latestVersion == CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter::CI_VERSION)
  {
    echo 'Updated';
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'Not updated';
  }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
   $can_read_url = 0; echo "Cannot check if updated.";
}

